# How to get last sub directory from string path

Tags: php, regex

Hi I am getting a value from an array as a string, now I want to remove some specific part:

The string is generated dynamically:

```
1categoryads/Academic/0Chrysanthemum.jpg

1categoryads/Arts/0Chrysanthemum.jpg

1categoryads/Sports/0Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

Here I want to remove string  before first / and after / i tried but i am not able to achieve my desired output.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Avinash Raj  expected ouput is Academic,Arts,Sports

Comment: `i tried but i am not able to achoeve my desired output.` , post your attempt.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: `echo $whatIwant;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're showing, use the appropriate functions for paths/files:

```
$result = basename(dirname("1categoryads/Academic/0Chrysanthemum.jpg"));
```

`dirname` gets the directory name of the path and then `basename` gets the "end" or base of that.

If you know the position of what you want in an arbitrary string, then use string functions.  If it is a path and you want a directory etc. then use this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode`:

```
$array = explode('/', $string); # Split the string at / characters
$string = $array[1]; # use the second segment
```